# Is it possible to get some fingerprinting protection features of TBB in regular Firefox for non-Tor browsing?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting, add-on, tor-button

I'd like to prevent Firefox from reading canvas, for example. As far as I understand, this is functionality of Tor Button extension which is part of Tor Browser Bundle, but it implies using Tor. What if I want to achieve the same protection in the regular Firefox for non-Tor browsing, what should I use?

Update: question was marked as duplicate of [How to dissconnect Tor browser from the Tor network](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10367) but I don't think so, because that question is about using TBB without Tor, and the consensus was that it's a very bad idea. And my question is about the opposite — getting TBB-level browser hardening in a regular Firefox (or some fork) for using it with regular browsing (not over Tor).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dissconnect Tor browser from the Tor network](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/how-to-dissconnect-tor-browser-from-the-tor-network)

Comment: Of note is that the canvas fingerprinting is a [hardcoded patch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/commit/?h=tor-browser-45.7.0esr-6.5-1&id=f0d39fb5ada12c963015383ca26fee0b1f4787df), not handled by Tor Button.

Comment: @canonizingironize hmm, so that means the only real solution is to ditch "official" Firefox and use a fork which includes the same patch?

Comment: Right, you can either get Tor Browser to not use Tor or you can apply the patches to Firefox manually (painful!). Note that the patches are against [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) and not the latest Firefox so it's probably not something you want to get into without knowledge of C++ and the Firefox code and build systems.

Comment: @canonizingironize but maybe somebody does this already?

Comment: Sure, essentially the `firefox` binary shipped with Tor Browser is exactly that, but I don't know of anyone packaging it specifically.

Comment: @canonizingironize hmm, what if I take a regular Firefox ESR installation and replace that binary with the one from Tor Browser? I guess this stunt might work :D