# Torbrowser over an SSH tunnel with SOCKS 5

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ssh

I am trying to use Torbrowser without the tor network, but instead trying to use ssh as a socks proxy (ssh -D).

Using Torbrowser without any proxy (neither tor nor ssh) works fine. As soon as I add the ssh socks proxy, I am seeing the following behavior: the first web page usually loads fine; in one of the next pages Torbrowser seems to load forever on some of the elements; after the 3rd or 4th page, it hangs on the entire page, loading forever (well, too long for me to wait anyway). Doing the same with Firefox 52 ESR works fine; only Torbrowser 7 has this problem.

Any ideas why this might happen? Maybe it is due to the socks extensions in tor?

Let me emphasize that I am *not* trying to run tor over ssh or vice versa. Essentially what I am trying to do is to use an ssh tunnel in place of the tor network.

tnx

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be aware that using ssh offers very little, if any, privacy protection. I strongly recommend against it. See [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/how-to-dissconnect-tor-browser-from-the-tor-network/10371#comment16980_10371) for why.

Tried to reproduce the issue, appears to work fine here. I set it up like this:

- disabled addon Torbutton
- disabled addon TorLauncher
- set proxy port via environment `TOR_SOCKS_PORT=1234` (assuming `ssh -D 1234 …`)
- disabled launching Tor via environment `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1`