# Page Load Time add-on in Tor Browser Bundle not working

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I've just configured `Tor Browser Bundle` as a normal browser (that is directing the traffic over the normal internet route rather than the Tor network) by following [these](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/how-to-run-the-tor-browser-without-the-bundled-tor-proxy) (and [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1117383/can-i-use-tor-browser-without-using-tor-network)) instructions. This is just for some measurements I need to do, and I am not going to use this for normal browsing so anonymity is not a concern over here.

So, basically, what I want to do is to measure the page load time of a website loaded on this modified `Tor` browser. I was using [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/apptelemetry/) add-on in `Firefox (52.0.2)` previously but it ceases to work in `Tor`. I was wondering, are there any configurations (for example in `about:config`) that Tor has that prevent this add-on from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tor Browser disables a lot of performance timing options since they can be used in side-channel and fingerprinting attacks from javascript on webpages.

The extension code does this

```
function reportTiming() {
  self.port.emit('timing', JSON.stringify(performance.timing));
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (performance && performance.timing) {
    reportTiming();
  }
}, false);
if (performance && performance.timing && performance.timing.loadEventEnd > 0) {
  reportTiming();
}
```

But since `performance.timing.loadEventEnd > 0` will *never* be true, it'll never report the page load end timing and so won't get a diff to measure from.

There are a few `about:config` setting you may want to look at: `dom.enable_user_timing`, `dom.enable_resource_timing` and `dom.enable_performance`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I looked into these and just set them as true but that doesn't seem to have any effect for some reason.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Enabled those 3 settings and reloaded the page with the addon installed and it gave me results?

Comment: It works now. I think the problem was that `dom.enable_performance` parameter seems to reset itself when I close the browser. It works when I enable it again. Any ideas on why it resets?